# Create A New Layout Block Magento Basket Page

Tags: layout, cart, blocks, xml

So I want to change a code block (discount vouchers) on the cart page. I need to create a new file to style this block.

The existing layout file (XML) has the following code:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="checkout.cart.coupon">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>rewardpoints/coupons.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <block type="rewardpoints/coupon" name="checkout_cart_coupon_normal" as="coupon_points" template="rewardpoints/reward_coupon.phtml">
            <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout_cart_coupon_reward" as="coupon_original" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

I'm trying to copy that by **adding** the following below that:

```
    <reference name="checkout.cart.coupon.short">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>rewardpoints/coupons_short.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <block type="rewardpoints/coupon" name="cart_coupon_points_short" as="coupon_points_short" template="rewardpoints/reward_coupon_short.phtml">
            <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="cart_coupon_points_cart" as="coupon_points_cart" template="checkout/cart/coupon_cart.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

I have created the new **phtml** files and for now, they contain exactly the same data. There are no ID conflicts.

These are being called with the `$this->getChildHtml('coupon_points_short');` code. Needless to say, the page is just empty. White. Nothing.

Could someone please advise me how to proceed.

Comment: I just cracked it! This file was actually correct, but it was referenced higher up in another layout template (checkout.xml) first.

I put a block in there:

<block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon.short" as="coupon_short" template="checkout/cart/coupon_short.phtml"/>
...now it works like a charm. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Please add this as an answer, mark it in two days as correct. You should be able to answer your own question when I remember correct (15 reputation)

Answer (score 1):

> I just cracked it! This file was actually correct, but it was referenced higher up in another layout template (checkout.xml) first. I put a block in there:  ...now it works like a charm. Thanks for taking a look.

This is the answer, and the question can be marked as closed.